# calling Servlet post method using javascript

Tags: javascript, servlets, post

i need to call servlet post method using javascript ,i have done like this

```
 var iframe= document.getElementById("iframe");
 iframe.src = "MyServlet";
```

Answer (score 1):

You have done it incorrectly.

You need to set the `src` to a URL that will invoke the servlet, such as

```
iframe.src = "/Path/To/Something";
```

If you want to send a POST request, you'll need to create a `<form action="/Path/To/Something" target="IFrameName">` and call `submit()`.

---

Note that it is more efficient to use AJAX, with an XMLHttpRequest.  The easiest way to do that is with [jQuery](http://jquery.com):

```
$.get("/Path/To/Something");
```

(Although you would want to call `$.post`)

Comment: just let it be `post(..)` (it's what he wants)

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to `POST` to a server:

- submit a `<form>` with `method="POST"`
- use ajax and specify `POST` as method

All other options are invoking `GET`

That said, `MyServlet` is unlikely to be a valid path. You need to specify the path that you configured as `<url-pattern>` in web.xml